# The meaning of the term "write"

Tags: terminology

Sometimes, when I am reading mathematical writing, I will see something like

"To prove this, write..."

followed by some expressions. I am wondering what "write" means contexts like these, and when it is appropriate to use this term in a proof.

Comment: When I see this, I think it usually means that an explicit description of some kind is possible, and can be literally written down. But an example would be helpful.

Comment: The picture to have in mind is that the author is sitting by you and you are working together to find the proof. So the author is asking you to write something down so that you can discuss it.